# How to "migrate" one object to another object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

Given two object, named: `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`:

```js
var ObjectA = {
    config1: "5",
    config2: "6",
    config3: "7"
}
var ObjectB = {
    config1: "1",
    config2: "2",
    config4: "3",
    config5: "4"
}
```

How can I copy from `ObjectB` to `ObjectA` so that `ObjectA` have the same properties of `ObjectB` while the values of properties in `ObjectA` is kept and values from `ObjectB` `that doesn't exist` in `ObjectA` is copied to `ObjectA`?

Expected result:

```js
ObjectA = {
    config1: "5",
    config2: "6",
    config4: "3",
    config5: "4"
}
```

- `config3` is deleted since it doesn't exist in `ObjectB`,
- `config4` with `config5` are copied to `ObjectA` since those doesn't exist in `ObjectA`,
- **and** value in `config1` with `config2` are kept the same in `ObjectA` since those two exist in both of the object)

Comment: There are so many ways to achieve this. Can you post the code that you have attempted till now, so that we can help where you are stuck with.

Comment: Do it in two steps. First loop over the properties in ObjectA. If it doesn't exist in ObjectB, delete it. Then loop over the properties in ObjectB. If it doesn't exist in ObjectA, copy it.

Comment: @fast-reflexes That won't delete properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce`:

```
ObjectA = Object.keys(ObjectB).reduce(
    (acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: ObjectA[key] ?? ObjectB[key]}), {}
)
```

This will use the keys from `ObjectB`, take values from `ObjectA`, when they exist (with fallback to `ObjectB`), and populate an empty object with the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reducer function to solve.

```js
var ObjectA = {
    config1: "5",
    config2: "6",
    config3: "7"
}
var ObjectB = {
    config1: "1",
    config2: "2",
    config4: "3",
    config5: "4"
}

const res = Object.keys(ObjectB).reduce((prev, next) => {
  if(ObjectA[next]){
    prev[next] = ObjectA[next];
  }
  return prev;
}, {...ObjectB})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: If you're going to use spread why not just use it to solve the problem directly?

Comment: no, it won't be expected output is different.

Comment: I see, it has to only merge the existing keys!

Comment: The code work great for string or number, but for boolean, the migrated value will always be true except when both of the value is false. Like if `ObjectA` is `{a: false, b: true}` and `ObjectB` is `{a: true}` then the value `a` would be `true` instead of `false`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution that is more old school:
What this basically do:

- Loop over the properties in ObjectA. If it doesn't exist in ObjectB, delete
- Loop over the properties in ObjectB. If it doesn't exist in ObjectA, copy it.

```js
function mergeObject(oldObj: Object, newObj: Object) {
    var copyOfOldObj = Object.assign({}, oldObj);
    for (const key in copyOfOldObj) {
        if (!newObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            delete copyOfOldObj[key];
        }
    }
    for (const key in newObj) {
        if (!copyOfOldObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            copyOfOldObj[key] = newObj[key];
        }
    }
    return copyOfOldObj;
}
```